# Find out error of Android WebView loading an URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I use a Android WebView to display a URL, which holds a image gallery, with a kind of lightbox feature to show images in detail using Javascript.

When I call this URL in the Browser App. It loads fine, and works as expected. But when I load the same URL in a WebView of a Android App, the image overview gets loaded, but when I tap on a image to get the lightbox up, it does not show.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_image_detail_webview);
        String imageDetailUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.json_page_url) + imageGallery.get("detailLink");
        webView.loadUrl(imageDetailUrl);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
```

So JavaScript should be enabled.
The Apps internal browsers seems to behave differntly than the App Browser!?

Any ideas, on how I could narrow down the errror?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the js console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end all the suggested solutions didn't work for me. So I implemented a native image gallery for the image. I used this tutorial [Fullscreen Image Slider](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/) as a reference for building my own one. Works out pretty sweet.

Answer (score 0):

```
         wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



        wv.loadUrl("http://www.accelfrontline.com");
```

Try this code hope this will be useful..

Comment: I added the "setBuiltInZoomControls" call. "setJavaScriptEnabled" call was already in the code. I dont see the benefit in your code, over mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines to onCreate()

```
super.init();
WebView webView=new WebView(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//Add these lines according to your requirements
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);       
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
//webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);        
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);     
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setClickable(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());      
webView.loadUrl("Your webpage link");          
setContentView(webView);
```